# C/CPP for loop performance: test expression

Tags: c++, c, for-loop

Usually, a simple test expression in C/CPP for-loop is written using comparation.

```
for ( i = 0; i < N; ++i)
```

However, we can find other approach - using not_equal operator. (e.g. "A Tour of C++" by Bjarne Stroustrup)

```
for ( i = 0; i != N; ++i)
```

Any opinion on this? 
Is it performance issue or just style?

Thanks

Comment: This doesn't have any differences in performance. It is just matter of taste which is better (that us why others closed it as "opinion based"). You are beginner: you have to learn a lot, before even considering, if this kind of changes have any impact on performance (it is not). Now just focus on how to write correct program.

Comment: The 2nd is the usual style when using iterators in loops.  It's possible that the author wants a consistent loop style for ease of scanning their code.

Comment: There are iterators that don't have an `operator<`, but only support `==`and `!=`. Always using `!=` makes all you for-loops look the same. Not a thing in C though.

Answer (score 0):

You can check it [here](https://godbolt.org/z/Yje7xqYrE). There is no difference and the assembly code for both of them is identical.

> Is it a performance issue or just style?

Mostly style.

Comment: This is a somewhat questionable example because the upper bound is a compile time constant. Also, a compiler can reason about possible values based on a type, and you start iterations from the minimum possible value. If you make `N` a run-time variable and change type to a signed one (e.g., `int`) or start from `1`, you'll see [the difference in the assembly](https://godbolt.org/z/bhs7vGGb7).

Comment: @Evg Yes. But most of the time, for-loops are written with unsigned integers. That's why I focused on unsigned.

Comment: there should totally be a clear distinction between `JNE` and `JL` in the assembly, however the rest of it should be pretty much identical.